# Web Game Pre-Production

Tags: language-agnostic

So I have this idea that I've had since I started programming. I wanted to do it justice and finish it when I knew what I was doing. It would be a web game. Static graphics, HTML CSS and Php (no Javascript though). This would be my first web developing endeavor but thats not the point of this.

Instead of blindly running into the game I think I should do some pre planning but I don't know what. What should I do before I start coding?

If your too lazy to read it:

What should someone do to prepare for a web-game before coding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best first step would be to know your requirements. Start planning. Draw out on paper what you want each "area" to look like, what types of movement you want between areas, etc. Know what types of "exceptions" you'll have to the normal navigational rules (i.e.: can you fall through a porthole and end up on the other side of the game?).

The worst possible scenario is that you build large chunks of your game only to discover that your code doesn't appropriately suit your needs.

Comment: Hmm My game doesn't really have movement. In my mind it would be navigated by a tabbar that sends you to a different html page. That sounds good though.

Answer (score 0):

Write out everything your game encompasses, from this deduce your necessary classes, database models and try to get some 2nd opinions.

Also, consider using a framework like Zend to make things easier for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I once read a book titled [The Art of Game Design: A book of lenses](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123694965). I found it to be a pleasant, high level, nontechnical coverage of the subject. It's divided into small chapters called "lenses." And in one lens, the author explains how to prototype a game without using any software. One of the examples he uses is that of prototyping a First Person Shooter (FPS) using a few tokens, a rulebook, a stopwatch, and some dice.

Judging by the technical requirements you cited above (PHP, static images, no JavaScript), I think your game would be a good candidate for that kind of prototyping. Try it out, play it with friends, and if it's fun, then you can start to worry about coding. If not, then tweak the concept and the rules until it's fun.